# how to start a fragment from the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a activity , and i have a 2 fragments
When i move from fragment about a fragment , i use :

```
class a extends activity{
.
.
.
public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.frag, new Mobile());
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);

        trans.commit();
   }
.
.
.
.
}
```

the code of fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* pour creer le fragment */

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rechercher, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

how to start a fragment from the activity ? 
Note : I can not define `getFragmentManager()` in activity !!

Comment: Did you mean that you cannot use getFragmentManager() from the activity?

Comment: Use the support fragment manager instead. So change your activity to `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, then you'll be able to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` from the activity

Comment: @Olumide Error, I can not

Comment: Show us whole activity.

Comment: Its not possible that you cannot use getFragmentManager() in your Activity class. If that was so, it would never have been possible to attach fragment to FrameLayouts from activities.

Comment: no , normalment it is possible !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you don't have the activity context in the method onClick. Try to use :

```
getApplicationContext().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Please inform me after trying:
`Context context = a.this;
context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`